# Ordering across a generic relationship in django

Tags: django, sql-order-by, contenttype, generic-relationship

**For the example:**

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Container(models.Model):
    pass

class StoredUnit(models.Model):
    container = models.ForeignKey( Container )
    content_type = models.ForeignKey( ContentType )
    object_id = models.IntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey()

class UnitA(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    stored_unit = generic.GenericRelation( StoredUnit )

class UnitB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    stored_unit = generic.GenericRelation( StoredUnit )
```

**Given a container, is it possible to sort the 'Unit's by a field across a generic relationship?**

```
e.g.
container.storedunit_set.order_by('<genericly_related_unit>__name')
```